# magento 2 resize gallery images in product page

Tags: magento2, product, gallery, resize-image, pdp

thanks in advance
i need to resize the the product gallery images in product page magento 2

```
$all_images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
<div class="updated_all_images">
    <?php foreach($all_images as $child_new){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $child_new->getUrl(); ?>" >
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

here images are loading in  1080px*1400px,  i need to make those images size(dimentions) to 450*450